# Properties of Determinant of matrix sum/multiplication

Tags: matrices, determinant

!Hey there :)

I am currently working on a topic in control engineering and I'm currently looking for some way to relate determinants of matrix combinations to the determinant of the elements. 
Specifically, I would like to ask:

If I have the determinant of the hermitian matrix $A_H = AA^*$ (where $A$ is any complex n$\times$n matrix, and $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose), is it possible to draw conclusions about the determinant of $A$?

And similarly: If I have the determinant of the hermitian matrix $A_H = A+A^*$, is it possible to draw conclusions about the determinant of $A$?

Any hints are much appreciated, I hope I did not leave out anything important! 
Cheers and thanks, Christoph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a partial answer.**

For $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$,

$$\mathrm{det}(AA^{\ast})=\vert \mathrm{det}(A) \vert^{2}.$$

Using Schur's theorem, we know that there exists an unitary matrix $U$ such that and an upper triangular matrix :

$$ A = U T U^{\ast} $$

As a consequence, $A^{\ast} = UT^{\ast}U^{\ast}$ and $A+A^{\ast}=U \big( T+T^{\ast} \big) U^{\ast}$. It follows that :

$$ \mathrm{det}(A+A^{\ast}) = \prod \limits_{\lambda \in \mathrm{Sp}(A)} 2\Re(\lambda) $$

While $\displaystyle \mathrm{det}(A) = \prod \limits_{\lambda \in \mathrm{Sp}(A)} \lambda$.

In both cases, knowing $\mathrm{det}(AA^{\ast})$ or $\mathrm{det}(A+A^{\ast})$ is not enough to know $\mathrm{det}(A)$.

Comment: Hm ok, thanks. Do you know of any way to get information about the signs of the determinant of $A$?

Comment: Since $A$ is a *complex* matrix, its determinant is a complex number. It does not have a sign like real numbers do.

Comment: Yes I am aware, that's why I wrote signs in plural, but that was not very clear I guess. More precisely: I would like to know the sign of the real part of the determinant of $A$ :)

Comment: We do not have enough information to know the sign of the real part of $\mathrm{det}(A)$. Take $A \in \mathcal{M}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. Say that $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \left\{ \lambda_1,\lambda_2 \right\}$. Then,

$$ \Re \big( \mathrm{det}(A) \big) = \Re(\lambda_1)\Re(\lambda_2)-\Im(\lambda_1)\Im(\lambda_2) $$

But all we know is : $\mathrm{det}(A+A^{\ast}) = 4\Re(\lambda_1)\Re(\lambda_2)$ and $\vert \mathrm{det}(A) \vert^{2} = \big( \Re(\lambda_1)^2 + \Im(\lambda_1)^2 \big)\big( \Re(\lambda_2)^2 + \Im(\lambda_2)^2 \big)$.

Comment: Yeah that's more or less the conclusion I reached too, I was hoping for some mathemagic trick to work around it, but it seems I'll have to find some other way then. Thanks for the help! :)